# Can I use Java 8 Lambda expression in LHS of drool rule

Tags: java, drools

I want to use a supplier in LHS of rule for null check. code snippet is :

```
rule "Offer for Diamond"
when 
    productObject: Product(**Util.isNotNull(() -> type)**)
then
    productObject.setDiscount(15);
end
```

Where i am using supplier in Util.isNotNull(() -> type). When i run this code i get an error "*Line 7:41 no viable alternative at input ')' in rule "Offer for Diamond"]*".

Drools Core and Kie Spring version used is 7.36.1.Final.
Java version used : 1.8

I have also tried setting KieConfiguration properties "drools.dialect.java.lngLevel" and drools.dialect.java.compiler.lngLevel as system and KieBaseConfiguration properties but it did not work.

Can someone please help me out.

Thanks,
Rajesh.

Comment: What even are you trying to do in this rule? `type == "diamond"` will handle the null check already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. that could be handling the null. but in my case i have written the supplier to handle null in an object hierarchy Ex.

Comment: I've never seen arrow functions work in drools. In my experience the langLevel only affects the right hand side. Try replacing the arrow function with an anonymous interface implementation.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have tried this but it did not work.

Comment: Tried what? Your question should include any alternate code you have attempted to work around the problem.